# How to generate and insert millions of random numbers in a database and then save it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently working on a Laravel application and it has a feature where some certain users will login to generate unique, 12-digit PIN numbers.

Users with certain privileges should be able to generate a minimum of 1,000 or 10,000 PINS in one request.

**I am presently doing this, which is inefficient, as it's very costly in terms of server resources:**

```
class PinController extends ApiController
{

      public function __construct(Auth $auth, Pin $pin){
             $this->auth    = $auth;
             $this->pin = $pin;
             $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['index','show']]);
      }


     //pin generator - works
     protected function random($length = 14)
     {
         $pool = '123456789';
         return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($pool, $length)), 0, $length - 2);
     }


    public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
         $number_of_pins = $request->get('number_of_pins');//say 10000
         $user = $this->auth->user();
         $numbers =[];

         for($i=0; $i <= $number_of_pins; $i++){

              $number = $this->random(); //generate random 12 digit pins
              $numbers[] = $number;

              if(!in_array($numbers, $number) || !$this->pin->where('number',$number)->get())
              {
                    $this->pin->create(['number'=>$number,'user_id'=>$user->id]);
              }else{
                    $i--;
              }
        }

    }
}
```

This takes a **very long time** to execute and **fails all the time**.
I am considering using queue jobs to do this in chunks, but it might not be the best solution for my app's feature.

How can I do this in a way that doesn't take so long and doesn't fail?

Comment: a pin is usually one part of a multi-part identification system. This means that individual pins do not need to be 100% unique. If you need all 'pins' in the system to be unique, and non sequential, perhaps you would be better with something like uuid

Comment: @steve thanks for our comment. The pins are like mobile telecoms call cards or recharge cards which must be verified against a database record hence each pin needs to be unique. Please educate me more any better approach to this? I will look into `uuid` dough

Comment: @Steve has a point. It would be a lot easier to do something like `md5(uniqid(rand(), true))` and associate the result of this with a non-unique PIN. The PIN -> `md5(uniqid(rand(), true))` relationship would still be unique.

Comment: @Digitlimit Could you describe the constraints of the system - eg must be exactly x chars long, only digits (0-9) etc. Im sure there is a much better solution than random generation checked against previous computed values - the current solution will just get more inefficient over time

Comment: `"each been will be deleted from database when used"` wait, so it is possible to use a pin more than once?

Comment: @steve oops... nope its not possible. These pins are to be used verify the authenticity of a product by a consumer to avoid fake products. Means pins will not be deleted but marked as used by changing status from `0` to `1`

Comment: Then i would certainly use some kind of compound value - it will look like a random, but will actually be someting like RRRRAAAARRRR where `R`s are random numbers, `A`s represent an auto incremented number. Then you can just generate the random parts, and not care if they are unique in themselves, because the total, when combined with the incremented number, is guaranteed to be unique

Comment: @steve that's brilliant enough. How do I generate such compound number, MUST it be in this format `RRRRAAAARRRR` or is this okay `AAAARRRRRRRR`. how do i determine what should be AAAA

Comment: Thats up to you and your system requirements. i only suggested putting auto increment in the middle somewhere so it appears a bit more random to a casual observer. As to how you generate again depends on requirements - probably using the databases auto-increment field type would do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96799/discussion-between-digitlimit-and-steve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(!in_array($numbers, $number)` for testing the uniqueness will get slower and slower as your `$numbers` list grows..... rather than setting the `$number` as a value in the array, set it as the key, and then you can do a direct key check for duplication which is much faster than using `in_array()`

You're also adding `$number` to `$numbers` ***before*** doing the duplicates check, so you've already added the duplicate to your array (which is why it always fails)

The database check for every value is also a big overhead, best eliminated **if you can do so**

```
if(!isset($numbers[$number])) {
    $this->pin->create(['number'=>$number,'user_id'=>$user->id]);
    $numbers[$number] = true;
}else{
    $i--;
}
```

Comment: This code has a logic error in that pins that are not in the local array could still exisit in the db

Comment: Note the above comment was referring to your earlier edit (where `!isset($numbers[$number]` short circuits the conditional, but still applies

Comment: That's a neater code. Thank you. Should I generate all the PINS first then insert in database? I set a `unique` constraint on a database column for `number`

Comment: @Steve `The database check for every value is also a big overhead, best eliminated if you can do so`.... editing to highlight relevant words

Comment: Using a unique constraint in the database would probably be better for testing duplicates there, rather than executing a get query for every check, but you'd need to tests because finding duplicates that way would add overhead, but would still probably be less overhead than 10000 get queries

Comment: If you have enough memory though, read the list of existing pins from the database to another array can be done in a single query, and test against that array instead of a db check for each individual pin

Comment: If you do that, use the same approach of getting the values as keys so you can do the same isset check rather than in_array